# read score from txt file in c (visual studio 2017)

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, scanf

I want to get some integers from txt file to print scores.

However when I run this code, the command prompt disappears.

I dont know why.

**score.txt**

```
88
90
75
100
84
72
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

int i,data;
FILE* fp;

fopen_s(&fp,"score.txt", "r");

if (fp == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "file open error\n");  
    exit(1);
}
i = 1;
while ((fscanf_s(fp, "%d", &data)) != -1){ // EOF
    printf("%d \n", data);  

}
fclose(fp);

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated, but better stop using these stupid MS-specific `*_s` functions. They're incompatible with some similar functions provided by standard C and IMHO utterly pointless. While at it, `system("pause")` is also a very bad idea (and specific to windows). If you want to wait for some input, you could try a simple `getchar()`.

Comment: I recommend you read what [`scanf` (and family)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) actually returns. It might return something *other* than `-1` if there's a problem. And don't use `-1` for `EOF`, use the standard macro instead.

Comment: i think the problem might be related to visual studio 2017(the reason i used fscanf_s instead of fscanf)

Comment: Some further recommendations: Read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert. Learn how to use a debugger to step through your code, line by line. And save what `fscanf_s` returns in a separate variable that you can check while stepping through the code. And of course make sure that the file doesn't contain any non-digit characters except whitespace (line e.g. newlines), for this I recommend a hex-editor.

Comment: @heepak I think the reason is using `fscanf()`s return value incorrectly, see Someprogrammerdude's comment. Using VS 2017 is **no** reason to use `fscanf_s()`, btw.

Comment: Are you able to compile and execute a simple "Hello World" program? I suppose your problem is not related to your code (which is more or less correct) but it's probably related to the usage of VS2017 (buggy installation, buggy configuration,...)

Comment: Other idea: add `system("pause");` right before `exit(1);` and tell us what happens.